# Error 3265 - Field exists in recordset

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

All,

I'm trying to populate an activexlist view, but am getting Error 3265.

The code to populate it is:

```
Do Until rs.EOF
        Set lstItem = ctlListView.ListItems.Add()
        lstItem.text = rs!EntityID
        lstItem.subitems(1) = Nz(rs!Class, "")
        lstItem.subitems(2) = Nz(rs!Bundle, "")
        lstItem.subitems(3) = Nz(rs!Reference, "")
        lstItem.subitems(4) = Nz(rs!DisplayReference, "")
        lstItem.subitems(5) = Nz(rs!CalculatedReference, "")
        lstItem.subitems(6) = Nz(Format(rs!EntityDate, "d mmm yyyy"), "")
        lstItem.subitems(7) = Nz(Format(rs!EntityTime, "hh:mm am/pm"), "")
            lstItem.subitems(8) = Nz(rs!Description, "")
[...]
```

And the recordset that's triggering the error is:

```
SELECT p_Primary_1.EntityID, p_Primary_1.Class, p_Primary_1.Reference, p_Primary_1.Bundle, p_Primary_1.EntityDate, p_Primary_1.EntityTime, p_Primary_1.Description, p_Primary_1.DisplayReference, p_Primary_1.CalculatedReference, p_Primary.EntityID 
FROM p_Primary AS p_Primary_1 INNER JOIN (p_Primary INNER JOIN JunctionTable ON p_Primary.EntityID = JunctionTable.PK1) ON p_Primary_1.EntityID = JunctionTable.PK2 
WHERE (((p_Primary.EntityID) = 46) AND ((JunctionTable.RelationshipType) = 'EXEX'));
```

I get the error on line

```
lstItem.text = rs!EntityID
```

I presume that is because "EntityID" exists twice in the recordset (p_Primary_1.EntityID and P_Primary.EntityID).

How do you avoid the error?  (e.g., is it possible to simply add the first object in the collection (which will always be "EntityID")?)

Comment: If the 2 `EntityID`s are the same, just return it once. If they're different, alias one of them.

Comment: ...well that was painfully simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responding to your questions in opposite order ...

> is it possible to simply add the first object in the collection (which will always be "EntityID")?

Yes, you can reference a recordset field via its (zero-based) index.  So the first field is `rs.Fields(0)` or `rs(0)`

Incidentally you can use `rs.Fields(0).Name` to see the name Access is using for that field in the recordset.

> How do you avoid the error?

If you use `Fields(0)`, you would need to ensure it gets updated as needed when/if the `SELECT` is modified.

If you really need both `EntityID` fields in the query, alias one or both ...

```sql
SELECT p_Primary_1.EntityID AS EntityID1, p_Primary.EntityID AS EntityID0
```

Otherwise, just `SELECT` one of those 2 `EntityID` fields.